# Saving p.value of a test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

i used jarque-bera test in a for cycle and i need to save the p-value of the test in a vector. the output of the test looks like this:

```
Jarque Bera Test
data:  rlnorm(5, 5, 0.5)
X-squared = 0.62894, df = 2, p-value = 0.7302

Skewness

data:  rlnorm(5, 5, 0.5)
statistic = 0.10626, p-value = 0.9227

Kurtosis

data:  rlnorm(5, 5, 0.5)
statistic = 1.2755, p-value = 0.4312
```

so when i try to save it with

```
JarqueBera.test(rlnorm(30,5,0.5))$p.value
```

it saves a NULL value. i understand that i didn't specify which p.value i want to save which is probably the problem, i just didn't find a way to do so. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which package are you using? If you use `tseries` you can just pull out the p values.

```
> library(tseries)
> set.seed(1)
> jarque.bera.test(rlnorm(30,5,0.5))$p.value
[1] 0.7171779
```

Comment: i used tsoutliers but this worked, thanks :)